# android set max value of date < API level 11

Tags: android, api, date, dialog, datepicker

In my app I have `editText`, clicking on it calls `openDatePicker()` function.

```
protected void openDatePicker() {
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, dayOfMonth);
            Date birthDate = calendar.getTime();
            setDate(birthDate);
        }

    };
    DatePickerDialog dialog = prepareDatePickerDialg(mDateSetListener);
    dialog.show();
}
```

I must set max value when user will choose date. So can anybody suggest me something? thanks

Comment: There's a way, but it's not pretty and you have to extend DatePickerDialog...

Comment: If you're targeting API level 11 and up, you can get the `DatePicker` instance from the dialog and call `setMaxDate(long)` on it. For older devices, an alternative is to use a backported version, [like this one](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker) (although it has some drawbacks too).

Comment: Thank you very much , and please live your comments like an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

As per earlier comment:

If you're targeting API level 11 and up, you can get the `DatePicker` instance from the dialog and call `setMaxDate(long)` on it. For older devices, an alternative is to use a backported version, [like this one](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker) (although it has some drawbacks too).

Comment: I mean that I run it as single application , and it crashes when I  push one of buttons named "Darked themed" and "Light Themed"